# How to exclude or skip specific directory while running 'go test'

Tags: go, testing, goland

```
go test $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/) -coverprofile .testCoverage.txt
```

I am using the above command to test the files but there is 1 folder with the name "Store" that I want to exclude from tests. How it can be done?

Comment: `./...` doesn't include `./vendor`, so you don't need that grep. Otherwise, what's wrong with another grep?

Comment: As of Go 1.9, or so, `./...` already excludes the vendor directory. Upgrade to a newer version of Go.

Comment: @Flimzy my version is already : go version go1.11.1 linux/amd64

Comment: Good. Then you don't need that `grep -v /vendor/` stuff.

Comment: if they ignore vendor, they could allow this as option - e.g. I would like to skip also mocks directory.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're already doing it:

```
$(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
```

The `grep -v /vendor/` part is to exclude the `/vendor/` directory.  So just do the same for your `Store` directory:

```
go test $(go list ./... | grep -v /Store/) -coverprofile .testCoverage.txt
```

Note that excluding `/vendor/` this way is not necessary (unless you're using a really old version of Go). If you are using an old version of Go, you can combine them:

```
go test $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/ | grep -v /Store/) -coverprofile .testCoverage.txt
```