# How to avoid running particular test with -run flag without skipping?

Tags: go, testing

I know that I can specify which tests are meant to run by using `-run` flag like so:

```sh
go test -run=TestUpdateAll//Assignments
```

But how can I do that to make `go test` **not run** a particular test?

Let's say I don't wont the above test to be run. How to do that?

**EDIT**

Maybe this is crucial to understand my problem: the tests that I'd like to run are generated by third party tools with which I'm still trying to resolve an issue that's causing the above.

Therefore I cannot really add flags in source or use `t.Skip()` etc.

Comment: You'd have to write an elaborate regexp which matches anything but the test to exclude. There is no direct "exclude this" flag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip some tests with go test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030059/skip-some-tests-with-go-test)

Comment: There is no such option in `go test`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55224561/13860

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to do this (that doesn't involve constructing a regexp that matches everything except your set of tests), but you can add a flag yourself if you have a specific test (or set of tests) you'd like to skip frequently.

In your test file:

```
var skipPlz = flag.Bool("skip_assignments", false, "skip the assignments test")

func TestAssignments(t *testing.T) {
   if *skipPlz { t.Skip("-skip_assignments set") }
   .. remainder of test
}
```

With this code, you can run your go test command with the `-skip_assignments` flag to skip this test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you see my edit? That should shed some more light on my problem.